# Динамическое выделение памяти под указатель (c++)

Tags: c++, указатели, new

Впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть указатель на структуру **LPPOINT** - (***LPPOINT**) и под него надо выделить память. Выделить память по классике как `int *i=new int`, я могу, а вот под указатель.
Пробовал `LPPOINT lp=new sizeof(*lp);`
Ругается на `sizeof`.
Подскажите как правильно выделить память при помощи `new`.

Comment: `LPPOINT` - это уже указатель на структуру `POINT`. Если вы выделяете память под то, на что он указывает - т.е. под `POINT` - то nfr и пишете: `LPPOINT lp=new POINT;`. Правда, в вопросе у вас говорится "*есть указатель ... под него надо выделить память*" и получается, что нужно выделить память только для указателя :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто думал, что надо с указателем танцевать.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, можно извратиться, как вы пытались - например, так:

```
LPPOINT lp = new std::decay_t<decltype(*lp)>;
```

А можно просто посмотреть в документацию и выяснить, что `LPPOINT` - это тип указателя на `POINT` и, соответственно, написать просто

```
LPPOINT lp = new POINT;
```